# EOFError - end of file reached when using Zoho mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp

I am using Zoho mail to send email from my Rails application. But I am getting `EOFError - end of file reached` error when trying to send email. Below is my configuration for `development.rb`

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.zoho.com",
    :port                 => 465,
    :user_name            => 'info@mydomainname.com',
    :password             => 'zoho_mail_password',
    :authentication       => :login,
    :ssl                  => true,
    :tls                  => true,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Here is error from my log file

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7481ms (ActiveRecord: 2.1ms | Allocations: 44097)

EOFError - end of file reached:
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:19:in `create'
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. I had to set the default address in `application_mailer.rb` file

`default from: 'Business Name <info@mydomainname.com>'`